# OpenXML to Excel: CellFormat Problem - Open Excel-Template and insert datatable to existing Excel-Table with formatted columns

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am getting some data as JSON via RESTful web api and transforming it into a datatable.
Afterwards I want to open an "Excel template" (*.xlsx) with OpenXML and insert the datatable into an Excel table.
The Excel spreadsheet contains the headers and a blank row with no data. The columns are formatted (text, number, ... , left-justified, etc.) like this:

```
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| Quantity | QuantityUnit | ItemDescription |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| number   | Text         | Text            |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
```

The content of the "Excel-Template" looks like this:

```
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| Quantity | QuantityUnit | ItemDescription |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
|          |              |                 |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
```

My code so far:

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "ImportData").First();
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;
                //workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = GetStylesheet();
                //workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = GenerateStylesheet();
                workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();
                SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

                foreach (DataRow item in multiLevelBomDatatable.Rows)
                {
                    Row row = new Row();
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Cell cell = new Cell();
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            string sValue = item[i].ToString();
                            //double value = double.Parse(item[i].ToString());
                            //decimal dValue = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue);
                            CellValue cellValue = new CellValue
                            {
                                Text = sValue
                            };
                            cell.Append(cellValue);
                            //cell.CellValue = new CellValue(sValue);
                            //cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                            //cell.StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)2U;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(item[i].ToString());
                            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                        }

                        row.Append(cell);
                    }
                    sheetData.Append(row);
                }

                //find the table
                Table table = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Table.Name == "ImportData")?.Table;
                //update the reference of the table (11 is 10 data rows and 1 header)
                string maxRow = Convert.ToString(multiLevelBomDatatable.Rows.Count + 1);
                string startRow = "1";
                string tableReference = "A" + startRow + ":AE" + maxRow;
                //table.Reference = "A" + Convert.ToString(startRow) + ":AC" + Convert.ToString(maxRow +1);
                table.Reference = tableReference;
            }
```

If the table is formatted in the template, the datatable is filled only from third row.

```
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| Quantity | QuantityUnit | ItemDescription |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
|          |              |                 |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| 0.421    | m            | Tesa            |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
```

The result I want should look like this:

```
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| Quantity | QuantityUnit | ItemDescription |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
| 0.421    | m            | Tesa            |
+----------+--------------+-----------------+
```

**How can I insert data into an already formatted cell with OpenXML?**

Comment: Have you tried with a higher-level library like EPPlus, ClosedXML, NPOI? The OpenXML SDK is a low-level API. With eg EPPlus, loading a list, DataTable or even query results into a sheet is a single method call, eg `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(myList);`. The method can include the desired table style, including one of the predefined Excel table styles. You get back an Table object that can be used to further modify or style the object

Comment: As for templates, in Excel you can specify named ranges, including tables. You can create a template file with a named table and add rows to it, instead of adding rows and then trying to convert and style them as a table

Comment: I have to take care of licences... OpenXML and NPOI have a MIT license, so I will inform me about this alternatives.

Comment: I already have a named table in my excel-file. I get it by ''Table table = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Table.Name == "ImportData")?.Table;''

Comment: You do that *after* inserting the rows though

Comment: How can I add my sheetData to the existing table?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos thank you for your advice. I switched to ClosedXml and everything works great :)